# We already have pipes & pattern matching at home!

Tags: code-golf

Inspired by this [tweet](https://twitter.com/thdxr/status/1697349989104550285?s=20) where a user stated the following:

> it's insane how much code would be cleaned up if JS got pipes and pattern matching
>
> i often do this since it's the best way to make use of TS inference and pattern matching would make it less hacky

```js
const result = (() => {
  if (scenario1) {
    return {
      type: 1,
      thing: scenario1.thing
    }
  }
  if (scenario2 && other.foo) {
    return {
      type: 2,
      thing: other.foo
    }
  }
  return {
    type: 3,
    thing: other.foo
  }
})()
```

In the spirit of this statement let's *"simplify"* the above logic to be as concise as possible!

### The Problem

Write a code snippet in the language of your choice which will return the following:

1. When `scenario1` is **Truthy** output: `{ type: 1, thing: scenario1.thing }`
2. Otherwise if `scenario2` & `other.foo` are **Truthy** `{ type: 2, thing: other.foo }`
3. Otherwise output `{ type: 3, thing: other.foo }`

#### Constraints

This exercise should be viewed in the context of a program which has already declared `scenario1`, `scenario2` & `other` either above or as globals. Answers should reflect the shortest way to do what the OP was trying to accomplish.

- Variable and property names should be the same as above (or as close as your language will allow) and should be considered global.
- Answers should return an object / struct / class instance containing two properties `type` & `thing`
- Assume these don't have a strict shape (since the OP's example was in JS) and can be any of the following: `null` | `undefined` | `{ thing: "baz" }` | `{ thing: null }` | `{ thing: 123 }`
- Shortest code snippet wins, bonus points if your language can include the `|` operator for example `x || (x | y)` over `x ? x : (x + y)` inspired by the [*we already have at home meme*](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/we-have-food-at-home). If two answers are the same number of bytes, the one with more pipes will win.

#### Input

To make this problem non-trivial

1. `scenario1`, `scenario2` and `foo` should be considered as globals and already declared
2. The should contain the equivalent properties as the JS example, but don't need to use the `.` syntax

#### Output

Output should be an object containing two properties:

```
{
   type: 1 | 2 | 3,
   thing: scenario1.thing | other.foo
}
```

It doesn't have to be JS style object, but it should be an object containing the properties.

#### Test Cases

| scenario1 | scenario2 | other | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `{thing: true}` | `{thing: false}` | `{foo: 'bar'}` | `{type:1, thing: true}` |
| `{thing: false}` | `{thing: true}` | `{foo: 'bar'}` | `{type:1, thing: false}` |
| `{thing: false}` | `{thing: true}` | `{foo: null}` | `{type:1, thing: false}` |
| `null` | `null` | `{foo: 123}` | `{type:3, thing:123}` |
| `{thing: 0}` | `undefined` | `{foo: 'bar'}` | `{type:1, thing: 0}` |
| `undefined` | `{thing: 0}` | `{foo: 'bar'}` | `{type:2, thing: 'bar'}` |
| `undefined` | `{thing: "js"}` | `{foo: 'bar'}` | `{type:2, thing: 'bar'}` |
| `undefined` | `{thing: "js"}` | `{foo: null }` | `{type:3, thing: null}` |
| etc. | etc. | etc. | etc. |

#### Quick Tests

```js
function test(scenario1, scenario2, other) {
  if (scenario1) {
    return {
      type: 1,
      thing: scenario1.thing
    }
  }
  if (scenario2 && other.foo) {
    return {
      type: 2,
      thing: other.foo
    }
  }
  return {
    type: 3,
    thing: other.foo
  }
}

console.log([
  test({thing: true}, {thing: false}, {foo: 'bar'}),
  test({thing: false}, {thing: true}, {foo: 'bar'}),
  test({thing: false}, {thing: true}, {foo:  null}),
  test(null, null, {foo: 123}),
  test({thing: 0}, undefined, {foo: 'bar'}),
  test(undefined, {thing: 0}, {foo: 'bar'}),
  test(undefined, {thing: "js"}, {foo: 'bar'}),
  test(undefined, {thing: "js"}, {foo: null }),
  test(undefined, {thing: "js"}, {foo: 'bar' }),
])
```

Comment: Are we allowed to return the string `"{ type: 1, thing: scenario1.thing }"`, or does it have to be a JS-style object (or map/dictionary in other languages)?

Comment: I feel like this question could have been put in [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) before it was posted, because requiring the *input* specifically to be named stuff like `scenario1` and `scenario2` feels off for code golf challenges.

Comment: On a related note, do the inputs have to be global variables (as in the provided snippet), or can they be passed as arguments? If so, do the argument names matter?

Comment: Your code gives incorrect answers for situations where `scenario1` is truthy and `scenario1.thing` is falsy; it should still be returning `{thing: scenario1.thing}` but the `||` redirects it to `other.foo` instead.

Comment: Also, both sample code provided are in the form of snippets, instead of full programs/functions—are snippets allowed as answers?

Comment: @SuperStormer yeah sorry haha first time posting, which would you recommend?

Comment: The usual default for code golf questions is full program/function.

Comment: I think the way it’s structured a snippet works best for this particular problem, variables should be assumed to be defined as globals. If the syntax in your language is different, just keep the property names the same.

Comment: Tried it in Python, abandoned due to all booleans and edge cases ;-;

Comment: @Gugu72 this one was tougher than I originally thought, even my example solution was quite broken and I had to take down. Should I loosen up the rules since it was meant to be fun and not so tedious?

Comment: "language of your choice".... but it has to be a language supporting dicts/structs/etc?  or other languages can choose some other representation?  if so, how flexible is that?

Comment: @Jonah sorry this wasn’t meant to be super strict, just an equivalent to the best of your judgement I would say is fine

Comment: @Gugu72 I gave it a shot in your place.

Comment: What happens if ```scenario1``` is truthy, but doesn't contain any ```thing```?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen in that case `thing` wouldn't be defined, so it seems `undefined` would be appropriate!

Comment: Can you give an example of what a bonus-qualifying answer using the ```|``` operator would look like?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen just updated with a clarification, tl;dr in the event of two equal length answers it will come down to which one contains more pipes | !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes (2 pipes)

```javascript
{type:(v=other.foo,o=scenario1)?1:2|!v|!scenario2,thing:o?o.thing:v}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pdFLboMwEAbgPaeYZBOQHBLIjopm1VMgFi6YQGR5IvOQIuKzUxOrbqAtUVVWfsz/2R7OtKN1JqtLsxWYs@ElcQAS6JuyEqcIGtkyRcDOC8rrcaEvECPYvFO5UZAS2O10yfXCooDAY3SC2fAcf46Z6B800XKu4Lk21umQ/eZzowXhQWMT7WC1cXNys70yQityVlSC5eTRWnzn3kjfkjP5Vym0ktlc1Nbner3Y/39oYx9Ba/BTx@4/x0kdv0D5RrPSdROoMyaorFD34nOoj8emZBJSD@JX6CFDUSNnPseTOxjU7eJ7jaaQYGwV7xhE4W3V3VZfmjkdj@ibUacGT3nDBw)

#### Commented

```javascript
{                  //
  type: (          // define the 'type' property:
    v = other.foo, //   copy other.foo in v
    o = scenario1  //   copy scenario1 in o
  ) ?              //   if scenario1 is truthy:
    1              //     set the type to 1
  :                //   else:
    2 |            //     set the type to 2 unless
    !v |           //     other.foo is falsy
    !scenario2,    //     or scenario2 is falsy,
                   //     in which case it's set to 3
  thing:           // define the 'thing' property:
    o ?            //   if scenario1 is truthy:
      o.thing      //     use scenario1.thing
    :              //   else:
      v            //     use other.foo
}                  //
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 109 bytes

Inspired by Gugu72's comment, and they sure were right about how hard booleans are to golf.

`undefined` doesn't exist, so `None` pulls double duty as its usual analogue of `null` and as that. If I have to explicitly handle a case where the input is the string `"undefined"` I will probably explode

```python
{'type':1if(s:=scenario1)else 2|(not((f:=other and other['foo'])and scenario2)),(t:='thing'):s[t]if s else f}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVE9TsMwFFbXnOJttqWASFiQpayMTGylgyE2cZXYxn5BiopPwtIFbsBh4DTkt5UqQHjye_p-9V7fXYeVNfuPUipAGZAynoCX2HoDd28tqrOrz2ZHsHOS8EwrGngRHqQRXtuMyTpIyF-osUip4oXFSnoQpoTxtybKWrJhw2Ih5YylFHlBsNLmkTAe1rjRCgKMYirOpkZ520DoAujGWY8QsNQmUdZDrY0EbaZNH_eQJz26pFMCKKARjspnUacj7zy4WvctWQLOa4N0Ks0m1_3XarWbk_Fb38oIh_Fa9PmGeejEyb3wJCY3to9yfCfjAs7yy5gchC7iH9CfdU-4_wSTbSBxcvod8zRAFsEBNR_gGw)

Comment: Nice, yeah this is solid!

Comment: I assumed dicts weren't object and was trying to do it using SimpleNamespace from the `types` module ;-;

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>180</s> <s>150</s> 138 bytes

```r
o="other"
s="scenario1"
`+`=\(x)exists(x)&&length(get(x))
list(type=(3-(+"scenario2"&+o))^!+s,thing=`if`(+s,get(s)$thing,if(+o)other$foo))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=zZNNTsMwFIQX7HwKY6rEVtIFYcPGN0EoaXESi2JT_0gpR-AKbMKCQ5XT4D5XbqgQQghVrOKJ503mk52XVzNuswusNLZLoRoj9WU5VRUo7Xph3rxr59fbZ80JaIIsJ2mKoLqo-Q0dmBikdTYssmwlVOd62gkXJEOrsEHd5lFwejWnRRquSFZoxm7PC1u6XqqO17KtaVC7Sctm8LKULQ02-Pas1WEgNno_u_8eACZwrIVCyL7gpDtj5oEmyb4yVZ9NFUMQy4EptOFk0Rjy94wIHcOlRO6MF7_BOyTEtlAn9H8ip6RKhfYc00PD2kQudHBNu679QH54TBNTvLZggOUpuPDCO3ynhVW5w0utXCMVbtQG5xCRHwOuvR92fP6fEsZ_bhzj8wM)

Treats non-empty lists as truthy (not R's default behaviour, but seems to be the intent of this question).
Handles the cases where global variables `scenario1`, `scenario2` or `other` are undefined (=not 'declared').

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>116</s> 94 bytes

```r
o=other
s=scenario1
`+`=length
list(type=(3-(+scenario2&+o))^!+s,thing=`if`(+s,s$thing,o$foo))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZIxTsMwGIUlRotDmFIRW0kHwtLFN6jYWKukwWksVf5b-7eUgjgJSxjYuQ6cBtcWaQpCzWQ_-fl9_p_8-ma6D5QWRe10hQo048_vDuvZ_HNpha2kLo2CWwICsJGGFGkhNlKvsSEbZZHhfisFu5ux9Meb36TA-fIqtRk2Sq9FoerCH2d2GnQG0xq8I1K-Li5fCLmmGmgPy4YqDyrCe4e4f1gseplHGTxxe5iI8XO54QKVrZ_DjsoOE_vHi8mqNBP-L-Z4GY2TY0Gxz1CZz3_y-eeox6jIGY5HwfxpbUjYudZnjanwlEJXDukjSKsTpBVoLJWmpd7TJAQnv3E759oDzY3ixU_RdXH9Bg)

Assumes that global variables `scenario1`, `scenario2` and `other` already exist.

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 70 bytes

*-4 bytes, thanks to Value Ink*

```javascript
{type:(s=scenario1)?1:2|!((o=other.foo)&&scenario2),thing:s?s.thing:o}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70kLz8ldcFN2-Lk1LzEosx8Q9vSvJTUtMy81BQumJiRbV5pTg5XfklGapFtdVp-vpWCelJikXotV1FqcWlOie3S0pI0XYubbtUllQWpVhrFCNM07Q2tjGoUNTTybcHa9YC6NdXU4CZr6pRkZOalWxXbF-tBWPm1ENM2J-fnFefnpOrl5KdrQOzRhMgsWAChAQ)

Takes Inputs as global variables

Comment: Since `other` is only ever relevant when checking `other.foo`, you can assign `o=other.foo` to save 4 bytes.